# Pandas groupping values to column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have dataframe look like this:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  0  1  2  1  0
1  3  0  0  4  3
2  3  4  0  4  2
3  4  1  0  4  3
4  2  1  3  4  3
5  3  2  0  3  3
6  2  1  1  1  0
7  1  1  0  3  3
8  3  3  3  3  4
9  2  3  4  2  2
```

I do following command:

```
    df.groupby('A').sum()
```

And i get:

```
   b  c   d   e
a              
0  1  2   1   0
1  1  0   3   3
2  5  8   7   5
3  9  3  14  12
4  1  0   4   3
```

And after that I want to access

```
    labels = df['A']
```

But I have an error that there are no such column.

So does pandas have some syntax to get something like this?

```
   a  b  c   d   e             
0  0  1  2   1   0
1  1  1  0   3   3
2  2  5  8   7   5
3  3  9  3  14  12
4  4  1  0   4   3
```

I need to sum all values of columns b, c, d, e to column a with the relevant index

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the index with df.index, and add it back into your dataframe as another column.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('A').sum()
grouped_df['A'] = grouped_df.index
grouped_df.sum(axis=1)
```

Alternatively, groupby has 'as_index' option to keep the column 'A'
    groupby('A', as_index=False)
or, after groupby, you can use reset_index to put the column 'A' back.